# SQL Server: why does this Delete query not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables `FinalList` and `RemoveTheseIDsList`. They both have the same primary key of `ID`.  I want to remove all rows from `FinalList` that are in `RemoveTheseIDsList`. So, I wrote this first query:

```
Delete from FinalList
    Where FinalList.ID not in (Select ID from RemoveTheseIDsList)
```

In theory, that query should have deleted every single row from `FinalList`. Instead, it deleted 0. I eventually settled on this clunky workaround (which does work):

```
Update FinalList set DeleteMe='Y'
    from FinalList FLL
    left join RemoveTheseIDsList REM on FLL.ID=REM.ID
    where REM.ID is null
Delete from FinalList where DeleteMe='Y'
```

My question is: why did that first query not work? Is there a quick fix that'll keep this query both functionable and small?

Comment: Are you **positive** `ID ` is actually the Primary Key of `RemoveTheseIDsList` as stated? I would suspect that it is nullable and contains at least one `NULL` - or that `RemoveTheseIDsList`  does not contain a column called `ID` at all and the sub query is referencing the `ID` column from the outer query.

Comment: What error did you get? Shouldn't that first query read `ID IN ()`, not `ID NOT IN ()`?

Comment: @MichaelHaren - The Left Outer Join query is doing an anti semi join though so I presume they do want `NOT IN` semantics despite the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say : "I want to remove all records from FinalList **that are in** RemoveTheseIDsList"

So it should be  :

```
Delete from FinalList
Where FinalList.ID IN (Select ID from RemoveTheseIDsList)
```

But your update is like a not in so maybe try this :

```
Delete from FinalList
Where FinalList.ID NOT IN (Select RemoveTheseIDsList.ID from RemoveTheseIDsList)
```

Comment: Could be rewritten as a join, depends what you prefer

`DELETE fl 
FROM FinalList fl
INNER JOIN RemoveTheseIDsList rtl ON fl.ID = rtl.ID`

Comment: I'd add a `AND RemoveTheseIDsList.ID IS NOT NULL` in to the `NOT IN` sub query just to be sure as that is my main suspicion.

Comment: If he got a null value In the finalList if he do the update I think every row of the left join would be null, that'S why it's deleting every record in the RemoveTheseIDsList table. So the first delete in my answer should be right.

Comment: @GregM - No, the presence of a `NULL` in `RemoveTheseIDsList.ID` would not affect the left join but anything `NOT IN (x,y,NULL)` will always return no results.

Comment: yeah but i'm talking the presence of a null in FinalList

Comment: @GregM - Who were you responding to? My comment explicitly refered to `NULL`s in `RemoveTheseIDsList.ID`

Comment: Yep, big misunderstanding, Was just thinking out loud, not referring to your comment, sorry. I was just pointing out why his update was working when he want all the data from RemoveTheseIDsList deleted from FinalList